# Reusing the same html/css code via JQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css, load

I would apreciate very much if somebody helps me.

In order to not repeat the same code many times, I have made a separate header.html file and included it via JQuery.
The problem is the content of the header (2 divs, a form,an image and etc.) isn't loading. 
What is the reason and how I can improve it?

thanks in advance for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all make sure that jQuery is included in your page. Then you need to do a ajax call (obviously putting this after where jQuery is included):

```
$.ajax({
    url: "http://example.com/your-template-file"
})
.done(function( data ) {
    $('#destination').append(data);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you will import the content using JQuery, so it cannot not be done until JQuery is loaded.
If you insist loading content using JS, please try to use

```
$(function() {
  //Your loading code
})
```

This will ensure your loading code is executed after JQuery is loaded.

BTW, if you are writing J2EE application, you can use Sitemesh, Tiles or Freemarker to dynamically construct your page content.
Hope this help.